# ビルドでCSSを書き換えるには？

Tags: java, css, sass

長文大変失礼いたします．

### 背景

XMLで書かれたドキュメント群を変換してHTMLにし、CSSや画像ファイルとセットでパブリッシングするのをやっています．日本語だけでなく多言語をやっております．今般お客様の意向で、従来CSSで`@font-face`で指定していたフォントファイルを、今はやりのWeb Fontに置き換えることになりました．

主な狙いは日本語フォントなんだろうと思います．サーバー側に置いたTrueTypeやOpenTypeのフォントを直接`@font-face`でアサインしてしまうと、フォントファイルの大きさはそれなりにありますので、ダウンロードやハンドリングに時間がかかります．Web Fontを使うと、HTMLに忍び込ませたJavaScriptで、そのWebページで使っている文字を調べて、動的にサーバー側から`.woff`でサブセット化して送ってくれるそうです．それならブラウザの負担も減るでしょう．（早いかどうかはいろいろ議論があるようです）

さて、Web Fontにすると、今までCSSの中で自分で`@font-face`を指定したものが、Web Fontのサービスが自動的に生成してくれるCSSの`.woff`への`@font-face`を使うようになります．Web Fontのサービスは、CSSの`font-family:～;`指定から、自動的に`@font-face`を自動生成してくれるようです．

ここまではいいことづくめだったのですが、問題が持ち上がりました．実はCSSの中には、`font-weight: bold;`が当たり前に書かれています．ところがWeb Fontの`.woff`を使用するようになると、ブラウザは自動的にボールドフェースをシミュレートしてくれなくなるのです．それまでTrueTypeのフォントファイルを`@font-face`でアサインしていた時は、ブラウザがボールドフェースをシミュレート表示してくれていました．

この結果、`font-weight: bold;`はすべて無視されちゃって、Webページはノーマルフェースだけで文字の表示という、実にのっぺらぽうなものになってしまいます．これはとても見ていられません．

これを解決するにはWeb Fontを使う限り、以下のようにしなければなりません．（英文フォントの例になります．ファミリー名は正確ではありません）

- 大元を取り仕切るCSSで`font-family: FuturaPro-Light;`とやっていたら
- ボールドにしたいときは、あちこちのCSSに存在する`font-weight: bold;`はダメで、例えば`font-family: FuturaPro-Book;`と書かねばならない．（これで太字に見えてくれます）

でもですね、フロントエンドのデザイナーさんが作ったCSSは、言語にほぼ全部共通で同じもを使っているのです．なので、運用側の都合で、ある言語ではWeb Fontを使用、でもある言語ではクライアントにあるsans-serifでいいやというのは非常に困るのです．`font-weight: bold;`くらいは、どのフォントを使用しようが、それを意識することなしに自由に記述したいものです．

ちなみに多言語ですが、`font-family`の指定は大本のCSSの一ヶ所でやっているだけです．もちろんアラビア語なんかのためのLTR/RTLには対応しています．（以下で少々触れますSassで吸収しています．）

### 考えた方法

仕方がないのでWeb Fontを使用する言語のビルドでは、最終盤のステップでCSSの中の`font-weight: bold;`があったら、そのメディアやセレクタを覚えておいて、最後に`font-family: FuturaPro-Book;`と追記してやろうか？？と考えました．

ではこれをどうやってやるかを考えたのですが、パブリッシングのためのビルドで、プログラムでCSSを書き換えるってそう簡単ではないですよね．システムがJavaベースなのでJavaのCSSのパーサーを探しました、パーサーでCSSを読んで、それをXML(!)に変換してしまう、そのXMLを読んで上記の書き換え処理をXSLTで実装して、結果をまたCSSに書き戻すというものです．Webで良く出てくる [CSS Parser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cssparser/) を試してみたんですが、次のようなCSSを食わせるとお亡くなりになってしまいました．

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
body { direction: ltr; }
body { font-family: "メイリオ",Meiryo,"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3","Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",HiraKakuPro-W3,"ＭＳ Ｐゴシック","MS PGothic",Osaka,Verdana,sans-serif; color: #000; line-height: 1.5; background-color: #fff; overflow: hidden; }
```

以下は試してみたプログラムの一部：

```java
public class Css2XmlImpl {
    private String mInputCssPath;
    private String mOutputXmlPath;
    
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param inputCssPath
     * @param outputXmlPath
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public Css2XmlImpl(String inputCssPath, String outputXmlPath) throws IOException {
        mInputCssPath = inputCssPath;
        mOutputXmlPath = outputXmlPath;
    }
    public void parse() throws IOException {
        InputStream cssStream = null;
        XmlWriter xmlOutput = null;
        try {
            xmlOutput = new XmlWriter(mOutputXmlPath);
            cssStream = new FileInputStream(mInputCssPath);
            InputSource source = new InputSource();
            source.setByteStream(cssStream);
            source.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            SACParserCSS3 parser = new SACParserCSS3();
            parser.setDocumentHandler(new Css2XMLHandler(xmlOutput));
            parser.parseStyleSheet(source);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.err.println ("IO Error: " + ioe);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Error: " + e);

        }
        finally
        {
            xmlOutput.close(); 
        }
    }
}

class Css2XMLHandler implements DocumentHandlerExt {
  // ここでSaxのようにCSSパーサーのいろんなイベントを拾ってXMLに書く．
}
```

こけたときの途中結果のXMLはこんな感じです．

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<css>
  <charset arg="UTF-8"/>
  <selector>
    <selector-item>body</selector-item>
    <property name="direction" LexicalUnit="ltr" important="false"/>
  </selector>
  <selector>
    <selector-item>body</selector-item>
    <property name="font-family" LexicalUnit="メイリオ" important="false"/>
  </selector>
</css>
```

どうも

```css
font-family: "メイリオ",Meiryo,"ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3","Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro",HiraKakuPro-W3,"ＭＳ Ｐゴシック","MS PGothic",Osaka,Verdana,sans-serif;
```

の`font-family`の記述がパージングできずに、その先おかしくなってしまうようです．結果は以下のように出ます．

```
Error: org.w3c.css.sac.CSSException: unknown error
```

確かにちょっと変則的な書き方ですが、これくらいのCSSがパージングできないようでは全然ダメですね．

### お伺いしたいこと

私が直面している問題は、Web Fontを使用するなら、フォントには依存しますが、どのような方でも共通じゃないか？と思うのですが、いかがでしょう？実際どのように解決しておられるでしょうか？

### 追記

実は、パブリッシングのためのビルドで、Sassを使用しています．なので、`.scss`ファイルの`font-weight: bold;`を、`@include bold-font`のようなmixinに置き換えて、そのmixinのbold-fontをSassのコンパイル毎に動的に生成しようかという案もありました．

［動的に生成するmixin：Web Fontの場合］

```css
@mixin bold-font {
    font-family: FuturaPro-Book;
}
```

［動的に生成するmixin：Web Fontでない場合］

```css
@mixin bold-font {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

でもよく考えるとCSSというフロントデザインを、Web Fontを使うか/使わないか？という運用の問題でmixinに書き換えるというのも何か変な気がします．フロントエンド側はそこまで考えずに、デザインするのが筋ではないかと？なので、できたら、最終版でCSSを一気に書き換える方法をとりたいと考えております．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: 一般的にアプリデザインに制約があるのでしたらデザイン設計やデザインコードの工程で制約通り作ることを第一に考えます。工程の最後に無理に立てつけるよりも前工程の適切なところに入れたほうが品質やコストは少ないはずです。

Comment: @keitaro_so 「デザイン設計やデザインコードの工程で制約通り作る」「前工程の適切なところに入れ（る）」⇒こちらが正解ですね．質問の趣旨としてはみなさんWeb Fontをどのように使っているか？ということだったのですが、最終的にプロジェクトはとにもかくにも前に進めなければならず、採用した結論は御指摘の方向でした．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@font-face`は同名の`font-family`でweightの異なるフォントファイルを複数登録できます。
例えば、weightの違う複数のwoff2ファイルを持つフォント "Foo Sans"があったとします。

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Foo Sans';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/fooSans-Regular.woff2') format("woff2");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;    
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Foo Sans';
  src: url('./assets/fonts/fooSans-Bold.woff2') format("woff2");
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;    
}
```

上記の様にフォントファイルを配置し、

```css
.foo{
  font-family: 'Foo Sans';
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.bold{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

というスタイルを用意すれば、html側で

```html
  <div>これは通常のフォントです。</div>
  <div class="foo">これは Foo Sans フォントです。</div>
  <div class="foo bold">これは Foo Sans フォントの bold です。</div>
```

と記載すれば、3行目のdivは期待通り Foo Sans の太字で表示されます。

自前でwoffファイルを配信するのであれば上記の方法で問題なくfont-weightの指定ができる（しかも当該font-weightの指定がないドキュメントであれば当該のフォントファイルはロードされない）と思われますが、例えばfontplusなどのサービスを使用している場合はscriptでフォントファイルとcssを生成しているので標準的な方法では難しいかもしれません。（エンタープライズプランであればこのようなカスタマイズに応じてもらえるかもしれません）
あるいは、これもfontplus限定の話ですがwebフォントのロードが完了したらコールバック関数を仕掛けることができるようなので、そのコールバック関数でcssの中身を解析して回答本文のような`@font-face`を生成する、という方法も考えられます。

#### 追記

コメントと、私が投稿時に考えていたアイデアを具体的にご紹介します。

fontplusのフォントは仰る通りjavascriptでドキュメントの中身を走査し、実際に使用されているフォントをDOMツリーに組み込んでいるようです（その際組み込んだstyleタグには特定のidが付与されているようです）

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FuturaPro-Light';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url(FuturaPro-LightのURL);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FuturaPro-Book';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url(FuturaPro-BookのURL);
}
```

javascriptのAPIで公開されている、フォントがロード完了したら実行できるコールバック関数内で、上記style要素を探し、以下のようなcssを追加します。

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FuturaPro';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url(FuturaPro-LightのURL);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'FuturaPro';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url(FuturaPro-Book);
}
```

font-familyは同名にし、weightを変え、src内のurlはスクリプトで追加されたurlを抽出して同じ値をセットします。
このcssを追加すれば、ドキュメント内でベースのfont-familyを `font-family: 'FuturaPro'; font-weight: normal;`とし、要所で`font-weight: bold;`が使えるのではないか、ということです。

ただし、javascriptでドキュメント内のfont-familyを走査しているのであれば実際に`FuturaPro-Light`などのフォント指定が出てこなければなりません。そこで、ドキュメントベースのfont-familyを

```css
font-family: 'FuturaPro', 'FuturaPro-Light', 'FuturaPro-Book';
```

というように指定すし（抽出対象が全文字になってしまいますが）、javascript側で代替フォント部分までフォローしてくれるのであれば指定したフォントを取得してないだろうか、ということろまでが私のアイデアです。

また、javascfriptのAPIには [フォント指定](https://fontplus.jp/usage/javascript-api/method#api-8)というものがあり、これを使用すれば上記のfont-family指定に関係なく指定のフォントが取得できるのかもしれません。

Comment: 詳細な回答に感謝します！@font-faceの御指摘はまさにそのとおりです．サービス提供もFONTPLUSだったので、そのような具合に出してもらえないか、一番最初にお客さんを通じてお願いいたしました．なんですが、FONTPLUSのJavaScriptがHTML/CSSを走査して使用しているフォントを検出し、@font-faceを自動生成しているようです．このため「使いたいフォントのfont-familyを指定してください」の一点張りのすげない回答でした．つまりboldにしたければ、font-familyでボールド書体を指定する以外の解決方法ないということです．（エンタープライズプランは無理だろうな～）「Web Fontのダウンロードが完了したらコールバック関数を仕掛けることができる」は魅力的ですね．これは①あらかじめボールフェースのfont-familyを仕込んで@font-faceを生成するようにしておかねばならないのと、②（これはこちらの都合ですが）フロントエンドを担当しているのが別の会社さんなので、簡単にJavaScriptをこちらで勝手には触り難いという点が残念です．しかしご回答大変参考になりました．

Comment: 途中送信してしまったので再度コメントを送信します。
fontplusとしては、使用方法を例示（例ではstrongタグでfont-family指定でした）で示していますのでそのような回答になるのは仕方がないと思います。（カスタマイズしたかったらエンタープライズプランへどうぞ、というのも商売として当然でしょう）
コールバック関数を利用した具体的なアイデアを追記しました。これはデザイン時点で組み込まなくても良いのでデザイナーの負担にはならないかと思います。
これは個人的意見ですが、タグやクラスのスタイル指定を工夫すれば特段問題ない話なので、フロントエンド制作側に製作時の制約として取り込んでもらう話なのではないかなと思います。状況、環境によりけりとは思いますが、発注側としてこのくらいの要望は横暴ではないと思っています。

また、回答本文の追記として私が具体的に考えていたコールバック関数を用いたアイデアを記載しました。願わくばご参考になりますように。

Comment: 「タグやクラスのスタイル指定を工夫すれば特段問題ない話なので、フロントエンド制作側に製作時の制約として取り込んでもらう話なのではないかなと思います。」⇒フロントエンド側は性格としては私と同じ側（開発側）となります．私自身はフロントエンドはやっておりませんが、最終的にWeb Fontで生じてしまう制約を理解していただいた上で、SassやCSSの開発をやっていただく方が良いという結論になりました．こちらとは別に回答は今まで知り得なかったアイディアも教えていただき大変参考になりましたのでAcceptさせていただきます．